# Kubernetes DNS Disk Utilization is High. Is there a way to tailor the logging to assist?

Tags: kube-dns

Can someone suggest what level of logging should be enabled for kube-dns and what parameters to use?  My kube-dns pod is using 23GB of disk space and I fear its related to logging.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: If only warning/error is important to you is enough to use --v=0, for more verbose output may you can try --v=2 with kubectl

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to resolve your issue:

You can change verbose of logs in theconfig of your deployment.

```
kubectl get -o yaml --export deployments kube-dns --namespace=kube-system > file
```

Edit the file, change `--v=2` to `--v=0` (it will disable all logs in kube-dns) and deploy it.

```
kubectl apply -f ./file --namespace=kube-system
```

Then clear the logs on you pods:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system  
kubectl exec POD_NAME /bin/sh
```

You can configure logs rotating using any of the available tools, [for example](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd#getting-started)  fluentd.